# How to apply a function that take multiple arguments which are both vectors?

Tags: r

```
chance<-c(0.11,0.12,0.13,0.14,0.15)
aaa<-function(x,y) {
  assignChance <- function (a,b,v) {
    if (a == 0)
      if (b == 0) 1-v
      else v
    else
      if (b == 0) 0
      else 1
  }
  sapply(x,assignChance,y,chance) # this is wrong
}
aaa(c(1,1,0,0,1),c(1,1,1,0,0))
```

I would expect the outcome as: 1, 1, 0.13, 0.86, 0

Is there any better way for this function. I feel my current attemp is quite ugly as in a functional language I can just use `Array.map3` plue `pattern match`.

Is there a vector version of `switch` just like `ifelse`?

Comment: This also works: `(a == 0) * ((b==0) * (1 - chance) + (b != 0) * chance) + (a !=0) * (b != 0)` as does `ifelse(a == 0, ifelse(b == 0, 1 - chance, chance), ifelse(b == 0, 0, 1))`

Comment: @G-Grothendieck. True but it does compromise legibility ever so little...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for `mapply` :

```
 mapply(assignChance,x,y,chance)
```

By using `sapply` in your code, you are applying the `assignChance` function to every element of `x` in turn, and you are passing as `b` and `v` arguments your whole vectors `y` and `chance`. So, for example, for the first iteration of your `sapply`, the resulting call will be :

```
assignChance(x[1],y,chance)
```

instead of :

```
assignChance(x[1],y[1],chance[1])
```

Comment: (+1) Juba, in addition to explaining the best solution here, maybe it'd be nice to explain what's going wrong with his code as well. Just a thought :).

Comment: Can the whole function be simplified further?